# Iterate through files in directory using wildcard inTypescript/ Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, typescript, wildcard

I'm a beginner using Typescript/Node and programming in general, but I've looked all over SO and the internet as a whole and couldn't really find a similar question to what seems like a common task.

So I have an array of filenames from a directory stored in a variable. I basically need to search the array and find filenames based on a wildcard.

I need to loop through the array and find anything that matches 'messages' and print the filename out. Ive tried something like the following but it didn't give me what I needed.

```
let files: any = [ 'message-out-bar.log','agent-all.log','messages-out-tabular238.log' ]

for (let i in files) {
    if (files[i].indexOf('messages') > -1) {
        console.log(i);
    }
}
```

Also, I want to avoid using things like RegeX or glob.

Comment: To print the filename, just use `console.log(files[i]);`; otherwise, your approach seems to be ok. (However, consider using a for-of-loop instead).

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is correct, however you need to show not an `i` which is index of an array, but `files[i]` which is an item of your array.

In addition, there is another way to get desired results using [fitler()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)  method:

```js
let files = [ 'message-out-bar.log','agent-all.log','messages-out-tabular238.log' ]
const target = 'messages';
const similars = files.filter(f => f.includes(target));
console.log(similars);
```